# Interactions between two websites

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, integration

I have two websites. I want to change the View of Website A depending on the user's selection on Website B without refreshing or loading the site again.

Kind of a MVC-Pattern where Website A represents the View and Website B represents the Model.

Is this possible? I only found examples with Single-Pages.

Thanks and kind regards.

Comment: have you thought about push notification?

Comment: Or WebSocket, or WebRTC...

Comment: Or polling with Ajax (if the change doesn't need to be instantaneous)...

Comment: yea, i think WebSockets is what I need here. I will focus on that but i'm open for maybe other advices. Thanks guys!